# How to pass argument in bash script to check the status of git repository?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have done following code so far and how can I pass the file path as an argument (insted of setting up in bash script) to bash script and it will check the status of git repository.

```
#!/bin/bash

repos=( 
  "/home/jeff/github/workshop1"
  "/home/jeff/github/workshop2"
  "/home/jeff/github/workshop3"
)

echo ""
echo "Checking" ${#repos[@]} "repositories for status"

for repo in "${repos[@]}"
do
  echo ""
  echo "****** Checking status for" ${repo} "******"
  cd "${repo}"
  git status
  git log
  echo "******************************************"
done
```

Comment: Your username is Sam but it says `/home/jeff`... HMMMMMM

Comment: Which file path do you mean? What do you want to pass it to?

Comment: I use Linux VM given by Uni ,I got file in "/home/jeff/github/workshop1" and github is my git repository. When I run the bash script I need to pass the workshop1 (file path) as an argument to the script and then it will show the git log details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$@` gives you the list of all arguments passed t
o your script.

Thus, you need to set `repos=("$@")`.

Comment: `repos=$@` will create `repos` as a string rather than an array. You need to use `repos=("$@")` instead.